# Socket.IO and express routes

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I would like to use socket.io and express routes and I have the following code:

**app.js**

```
var
  http = require('http'),
  path = require('path'),
  passport = require('passport'),
  userpassport = require('./lib/strategies/local'),
  githubpassport = require('./lib/strategies/github'),
  flash = require('connect-flash'),
  express = require('express'),
  logger = require('morgan'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
  session = require('express-session'),
  errorhandler = require('errorhandler'),
  csrf = require('csurf'),
  favicon = require('serve-favicon'),
  sockets = require('./lib/socket'),
  app = express();

var routes = require('./routes')();
app.get('/', routes.index);

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  var io = require('socket.io')(server);

  io.on('connection', function (iosocket) {
    sockets.setSocket(iosocket);
  });
});
```

**lib/socket.js**

```
var socket;
exports.setSocket = function(iosocket) {
  console.log('setting socket');
  socket = iosocket;
}

exports.getSocket = function() {
  console.log('getting socket');
  return socket;
}
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var sockets = require('../lib/socket');
module.exports = function () {
  var routes = {};
  routes.index = function (req, res) {
  var socket = sockets.getSocket();
    socket.on('app/create', function (data) {
    console.log('got app create');
  });
}
```

This does not work, I think it's because the `setSocket` function that appears on app.js runs **after** the page was loaded, therefore when I `getSocket` on the route it's not the latest socket (I can console log the given socket on the route, I can see there's a socket there, but I can also see that the `setSocket` runs afterwards).

How can I solve this?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but wouldn't express.io be fit to combine socket.io and express routes ? see https://github.com/techpines/express.io